# retrieve list of mathematics categories from dbpedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Is there a way using SPARQL to retrieve all topics of in dpbedia?

http://dbpedia.org/snorql/

That is to say is there a way to extract all the subfields of the topics listed here:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_mathematics_topics
```

The broad topics are lists here: http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Fields_of_mathematics

I would like a list which shows the parent class and its subfield.

Answer (score 4):

question 1:
depends on how you define topic....
you can query for instance for `skos:Concept`:

```
SELECT ?con
WHERE {
  ?con a skos:Concept
} 
limit 1000
```

[see result](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20?con%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?con%20a%20skos%3aConcept%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0Alimit%201000)

question 2:
you can query for `skos:broader` properties, like:

```
SELECT ?parent (?label as ?sub)
   WHERE {
  {
    ?sub skos:broader <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Fields_of_mathematics> .
    ?sub rdfs:label ?label    .
  } UNION {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Fields_of_mathematics> rdfs:label ?parent
 }
}
```

[see results](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20?parent%20%28?label%20as%20?sub%29%20?subsub%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?sub%20skos%3abroader%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Category%3aFields_of_mathematics%3E%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?sub%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B?subsub%20dcterms%3asubject%20?sub%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20UNION%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Category%3aFields_of_mathematics%3E%20rdfs%3alabel%20?parent%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

retrieve a list of the next level of sub-fields of the above fields with:

```
SELECT ?parent ?sub ?subsub
WHERE {
  {
    ?sub skos:broader <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Fields_of_mathematics> .
    OPTIONAL {?subsub dcterms:subject ?sub}
  } UNION {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Fields_of_mathematics> rdfs:label ?parent
 }
}
```

[see results](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20?parent%20?sub%20?subsub%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?sub%20skos%3abroader%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Category%3aFields_of_mathematics%3E%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B?subsub%20dcterms%3asubject%20?sub%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20UNION%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Category%3aFields_of_mathematics%3E%20rdfs%3alabel%20?parent%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve further subcategories?

Comment: How do i get this result in another language? I tried to get it in German with http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kategorie:Teilgebiet_der_Mathematik, but it didnt give any results.

Comment: one way would be to query the german labels for the same list, e.g. by substituting (in the last example) the optional clause with: 
`?subsub dcterms:subject ?sub . 
       ?subsub rdfs:label ?german .
       filter(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?german), "de"))`
you will also have to add `?german` to the select clause.

Comment: @kr1 your last query doesn't seem to work anymore, any ideas?